# String to 32 bit Integer in Java, with default value than exception

Tags: java, string, parsing, int

I have a string of signed integer value that could range from "+2147483650" to "-9638527412". I need to parse them to a 32-bit integer, such that, when the string value is above the integer capacity (2^31) it should return the nearest possible integer value. Using "Integer.parseInt" is giving out of bound exception.

**Example:**

```
input: "+2147483650"
output: "+2147483647"
input: ""-963852741258"
output: "-2147483648"
```

I tried to use existing functions, but I'm stuck here.

---

```
try{
    //num =Integer.valueOf(stringNumber);
    num =Integer.parseInt(stringNumber);
}catch(Exception e){
    num = -2147483648; // if stringNumber is negative
    num = +2147483647 // if stringNumber is positive
}
```

Comment: Use `BigInteger.valueOf`, then compare it to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `MIN_VALUE` as appropriate?

Comment: @LouisWasserman wouldn't `Long` be more efficient than `BigInteger`, with it potentially using a native 64-bit word rather than a class designed for arbitrary (unlimited) precision?

Comment: @Andreas that is outside of the valid input range that the OP specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your value range is limited to `"+2147483650"` to `"-9638527412"`, you can parse to `long` and check for overflow.

```
public static int parse(String stringNumber) {
    long value = Long.parseLong(stringNumber);
    return (value < Integer.MIN_VALUE ? Integer.MIN_VALUE :
            value > Integer.MAX_VALUE ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : (int) value);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(parse("+2147483650"));
System.out.println(parse("42"));
System.out.println(parse("-9638527412"));
```

*Output*

```
2147483647
42
-2147483648
```

Comment: ah, so now you agree with me! ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak Of course, that's why I deleted my mistaken comment. :-)

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, I decided to go with Biginteger as my range of value goes beyond 'long' too. This is the final code I implemented.

BigInteger value = new BigInteger(stringNumber);
            return ((BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MIN_VALUE).compareTo(value) >0)?Integer.MIN_VALUE :
                   (BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE).compareTo(value) <0)?Integer.MAX_VALUE : value.intValue());

Answer (score 0):

If there is no reason you can't use a larger datatype such as `Long` then you can just parse it as a `Long`. If the parse fails, it will throw a `NumberFormatException`.

```
try {
    long tmp = Long.parseLong(stringNumber);

    int result;
    if (tmp < Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        result = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    } else if (tmp > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    } else {
        // safe cast to int (java 8)
        result = Math.toIntExact(tmp);
    }
    // TODO do something with the result
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // could not parse
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the specified potential input range, this function will clamp the given string in the range `[Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE]`:

```
static int clampedStringValue(String s) {
        long n = Long.parseLong(s);
        if (n > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        } else if (n < Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        } else {
                return (int)n;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why box the value to `Long` just to auto-unbox it immediately?

Comment: @Andreas mostly from copying the line of OP's code that used `Integer.valueOf()` rather than `Integer.parseInt` - `Long.parseLong` would indeed be better.  As would some sleep :p